# I am trying to import xml file with some empty attributes to table. getting this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, xml, postgresql

```
def XML_get_fields_and_types_and_data_levels_3(xml_file_name):
    data_2d = []
    for child in root:
        grandchildren = child.findall(".//")
        fields = []
        types = []
        data_1d = []
        data_2d.append(data_1d)
        for grandchild in grandchildren:
            data_1d.append(convert_string_to_type(grandchild.text))
        if grandchild.tag not in fields:
            fields.append(grandchild.tag)
            types.append(get_type_of_string(grandchild.text))
    return (fields, types, data_2d)

def get_type_of_string(string):
    clean_string = string.strip()
    try:
        if  clean_string is not None:
            clean_string = string.strip()
            return string.strip()
        if "." in clean_string:
            clean_string = string.split()
            if isinstance(clean_string, list):
                point_or_segment = [float(i) for i in clean_string]
                if len(point_or_segment) == 2:
                    return 'POINT'
                else:
                    return 'LSEG'
            else:
                val = float(clean_string)
                return 'REAL'
        else:
            val = int(clean_string)
            return 'INTEGER'
    except ValueError:
        return 'TEXT'
```

Comment: What are you using to call these functions? Whats contained in the parameters counts a lot towards the error you're having :)

Comment: actually i want to convert one input into point,that's why i write down this function.but here when i try to strip empty attribute it gives error, how to handle it?

Comment: The first occurrence of `string.strip()` is not guarded by `if string is not None:`

Comment: @Saira `clean_string = string.strip()` is causing your error which you are calling _before_ your error handling. This line should only be called inside of your `try` block. 
A few minor improvements could also be made to your code, but assuming everything else is fine, the above should fix your issue (i.e. remove your current first line of the `get_type_of_string` function).

Answer (score 0):

the issue is the line-of-code (loc) after your method definition,

`def get_type_of_string(string):
    clean_string = string.strip()`

there `string` might be `None`, so the exception is raised. Instead of re-writing the method for you, which would easy for me but not be very helpful for you, I suggest you to re-design this method. Here are my hints:

- there is duplicated code
- the `split()` method always returns a list, no matter if the separator is found, isn't, so there is no need for this line to exists `if isinstance(clean_string, list)`
- then why is this conversion in place if then `val` is not used thereafter? the easiest way to evaluate a variable type is by using the `isinstance()` builtin method as you did it few lines above.
- try to split this method, in simpler and smaller methods, or try to simplify its logic.

Hope this hints will help you through. Enjoy coding.